# Determining the potential difference between two points

Tags: short-circuit, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

In the figure above, I want to determine the potential difference between the points d and c, where there are two batteries connected in parallel, and two resistances connected in parallel too.
I was given that the potential difference between f and d is 12Volts, so the current entering the parallel connection is 3A(using ohm's law).
And using Kirchhoff's laws, (Vb)₃ is 10Volts.
I don't know how to determine the PD between d and c, I would appreciate any help or explanation.
 And that is what I think in:

> the voltage of the upper wire: V=1*7=7 Voltas
>   And V=Vb+Ir (since the battery recharges) so V=8+1=9
>   And Vtot=7+9=16

And the voltage of the other wire:

> V=IR=2*2=4V and V=Vb-Ir (since the battery discharges) so, V=10-2=8V and Vtot=8+4=12V

But I still don't know how to determine the whole PD between d and c.

Comment: Are you told whether Vfd or Vdf =12V? Or is that part of the problem?

Comment: @Chu, no, it just said that the potential difference between f and d is 12Volts.

Comment: So there are two possibilities for the direction of flow of the 3A. Hence, two possibilities for the current through the 2ohm. Try both, and see which is correct.

Comment: @Chu, Acutally I don't know the answers, and I considered the flow of current is from f to d, and I determined the value of Vb₃ according to this, but I don't know how I could determine the PD between d and c, since they have batteries and resistances together.

Comment: You have the voltage between g-h (16V). g is directly connected to d (so it must have the same potential) and h  is directly connected to c so it must have the same potential. Hence d-c is 16V.